# Angular.js - Clear Text box when Google Autocomplete event fires?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, autocomplete

I want to clear the textbox value when google map autocomplete event fires. I am new to AngularJS so facing little difficulty. Can anyone help?

HTML -

```
<input ng-model="deployText" id="search_execute" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter locations">
```

JS Code inside Controller function -

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#search_execute")[0], {types: ['(cities)']});
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {         
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            angular.element(document.getElementById('execute_place')).append("<div style='float:left'>"+place.address_components[0].long_name+"</div>");

            $scope.execute.push({latitude:place.geometry.location.lat(), longitude:place.geometry.location.lng()});

            $scope.deployText = "";  //Here I want to clear the text  

        });
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: input box value is not getting blank. I want input box to be blank after selecting a city from google autocomplete. @AnikIslamAbhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$scope.$apply()` for non angular component in order to take change

like this

```
$scope.deployText = "";  //Here I want to clear the text  
$scope.$apply();
```